# Flask lambda gives "unexpected error 'wsgi.url_scheme'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda

Getting the following output from my lambda (testing from the AWS GUI):

> call as flask app
> unexpected error 'wsgi.url_scheme'

Here is my code:

app.py

```
import json
import boto3
from flask_lambda import FlaskLambda
from flask import request


app = FlaskLambda(__name__)
ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = ddb.Table('items')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return json_response({"message": "/healthcheck says: Hello from Lambda!"})

@app.route('/healthcheck', methods=['GET'])
def healthcheck():
    return json_response({"message": "/healthcheck says: Hello from Lambda!"})

def json_response(data, response_code=200):
    return json.dumps(data), response_code, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

requirements.txt

```
requests
flask-lambda-python36
boto3
```

Any idea what may be causing this? I'm really confused especially that when I use Postman or ApiGateway it works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with passing the request from lambda to flask but I get the same error even copying the code from https://github.com/sivel/flask-lambda (Readme)

Comment: Also tried using this library with similar results: https://github.com/slank/awsgi